# posix_spawn is failing while applying iptable rules

Tags: tcp, firewall, iptables, ipv4

I have a code to apply IPv4 Firewall Rules. Code will read rules from local text file and parse the data to form rule. Once rule is formed, using posix_spawn rules will be applied. Below is my code:

```
ApplyRule(std::vector<const char*> rule, const char* binaryPath)
{
pid_t pid;
int status;

 if((posix_spawn(&pid,binaryPath,NULL,NULL,(char* const*)rule.data(),NULL)) !=0) 
 {cout<<"Posix_Spawan_Failed"<<endl;
 } else {
        if (waitpid(pid, &status, 0) == -1)
        {
         cout<<"Status 1:"<<status<<endl;
        } 
       }
}
```

Here rule will have `iptables -w -o rmnet_data0 -p tcp -d 18.159.158.206 --sport 5401 -A VARIABLE_IN -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT --tcp-flags SYN SYN` and binaryPath will have `/usr/sbin/iptables`

When executed, Apply rule is failing

Earlier this code was working without any errors, Without tcp flags ApplyRule is successful. Now we added support for `tcpflags` support. As soon as `tcpflags SYN SYN` is passed in the rule, Apply Rule is failing.

If i pass same rule from command line it is working but when i pass from the code ApplyRule is failing in posix_spawn. Reading the rule and parsing the rule is not having any errors. Also i tried to hard code the rule before applying in the code, still it failed. Is it because tcpflags have two arguments `SYN SYN` separated by space ? or some other issue ??

I doubt whether Fifth argument passed to `posix_spawn` which is of type `char *const argv[restrict]` causing the issues because of space in `SYN SYN` ?